# How do I iterate through json message's nested array with jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

How do I iterate through this json message's nested array(i.e. "orders") with jquery?

```
[{"Type":"X","Symbol":"AAP","BidPrice":17.0,
"OfferPrice":0.0,"BidQty":9,"OfferQty":0,"LastTradePrice":17.0,
"orders":[{"BidQuantity":"12","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
"BidQuantity":"2","BidPrice":"16.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""}]}
```

I have tried the following way but it does not work

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
   $('#last').text(data[i].LastTradePrice);

   var ords = item.orders;  
   $.each(ords, function(x,ork) {
    alert(ork[x].BidPrice);
   });                                      
});
```

I get the following error in firefox console

ork[x] is undefined

Comment: Your JSON is invalid; the brackets are unbalanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my code to following way it worked for me perfectly well.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  alert(data[i].Symbol); /* retrieve values from first json array */
  if(data[i].orders != null){   
     for(var j=0; j<data[i].orders.length; j++){
        alert(item.orders[j].BidPrice);/* retrieve json values from nested array */
     }
  }
}
```

Sorry for the delayed response with the answer, I was seriously busy with work for a while......
Thanks all who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid at `"orders:[`, should have been `"orders":[`, you also forgot to enclose each object in `orders` array with `}`. In any case, below is corrected JSON.

In any case, you don't need to use jquery for things like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    alert(inputs[i].BidPrice);
}
```

Orders is of type array, I seriously doubt you need to use jQuery, but in any case:
http://jsfiddle.net/kyWGT/14/

```
var data =     
   [{"Type":"X","Symbol":"AAP","BidPrice":17.0,
   "OfferPrice":0.0,"BidQty":9,"OfferQty":0,"LastTradePrice":17.0,
   "orders":[{"BidQuantity":"12","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
             {"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
             {"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""}, {"BidQuantity":"2","BidPrice":"16.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""}]
   }];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
   $('#last').text(data[i].LastTradePrice);

   var ords = item.orders;  
    $.each(ords, function(i, ork) {
        alert(ork.BidPrice);
    });
});​
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning the mistake on json message, I have corrected that, but I need to know the jquery way since I have used all the scripts in jquery

Comment: orders is a nested array so I need to get all four rows out of that

Comment: in this way im only getting the first row of orders array

Answer (score 1):

`$.each` invokes the callback with the index and the item. The item does not need to have a property named like that index, that data has.

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    item === data[i];
})
```

So don't use `data[i]` but `item` in your code, and use neither `ords[x]` nor `ork[x]` but `ork`. Also: DO NOT use iterator functions if you don't need them! Javascript has built-in loop syntax :-)

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    $('#last').text(data[i].LastTradePrice);
    var ords = data[i].orders;  
    for (var j=0; j<ords.length; j++)
        alert(ords[j].BidPrice);
}
```

...which is much faster. Also, if you know that your result data has only one item, you can omit the outer loop and just use `data[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are still other mistakes in your JSON, the correct JSON I presume is this:

```
[{"Type":"X","Symbol":"AAP","BidPrice":17.0,
"OfferPrice":0.0,"BidQty":9,"OfferQty":0,"LastTradePrice":17.0,
"orders":[{"BidQuantity":"12","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
{"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
{"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
{"BidQuantity":"2","BidPrice":"16.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""}]}]
```

Assuming that is right, your jQuery is almost there.  In the second each callback, 'ork' is the order object, you don't need to index it with 'x'.  This should work:

```
$.each(ords, function(x,ork) {
    alert(ork.BidPrice);
});
```

If you copy/paste this code it should work, it works for me:

```
var data = [{"Type":"X","Symbol":"AAP","BidPrice":17.0,
"OfferPrice":0.0,"BidQty":9,"OfferQty":0,"LastTradePrice":17.0,
"orders":[{"BidQuantity":"12","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
{"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
{"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
{"BidQuantity":"2","BidPrice":"16.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""}]}]

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var ords = item.orders;
    $.each(ords, function(i, ork) {
        alert(ork.BidPrice);
    });
});
```

Comment: still im getting "ork is not defined" error in firefox console

Comment: I've added a working solution to my answer, if you copy paste it, it will work.  If it doesn't work ... you've got other problems :)

Comment: in this way im only getting the first row of the orders array. It does not print all the rows

Answer (score 1):

suppose this is your Json

```
   var sbk = 
     [{"Type":"X","Symbol":"AAP","BidPrice":17.0,
      "OfferPrice":0.0,"BidQty":9,"OfferQty":0,"LastTradePrice":17.0,            
      "orders":[{"BidQuantity":"12","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
      {"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
      {"BidQuantity":"5","BidPrice":"17.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""},
      {"BidQuantity":"2","BidPrice":"16.0","OfferQuantity":"","OfferPrice":""}] }];
```

this is your script :

```
  $.each(sbk, function(i, item) {
      var ords = item.orders;  
      $.each(ords, function(i, ork) {
                 console.log(ork.BidPrice);
                 alert(ork.BidPrice);
      });
```

**Check Here :** http://jsfiddle.net/JH6A7/10/

Comment: there's no { "Data": part in it